# Improvement - How does 'could' illustrate a fact? Why not use 'can'?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In view of user Dan Bron's generous suggested edit for and comment under [How does 'could' illustrate a fact? Why not use 'can'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/36828/8712), would someone please post it for my viewing?

From Dan Bron's comment:

> I tried to edit your question to enhance its clarify and visibility on the site, but I don't have sufficient reputation.

Comment: Three of us have now closevoted as *unclear what you're asking*. Please elaborate.

Comment: [There is no suggested edit to be posted here.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36828/how-does-could-illustrate-a-fact-why-not-use-can#comment68250_36828)

Comment: @snailboat, how did you create a link to a specific comment?

Comment: @DanBron Click on the date following the comment ("Oct 16 at 9:11").  This should put the URL of the comment into your URL bar, which you can then copy and paste.

Comment: @snailboat Ah, beautiful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone doesn't have permission to edit, they may submit a suggested edit that either gets approved, modified and approved, or rejected by someone with more privileges. The first time I used the suggested edit feature, I didn't actually end up submitting my suggestion because I was confused by the interface.

I don't know that Dan actually submitted the edit for approval, so I don't know that it can be retrieved. Usually if the edit is helpful, it is approved fairly quickly.

Comment: To clarify: I did not submit my edit for approval. I simply discarded it. I was using the mobile app at the time, and I was simply informed that I lacked sufficient rep to make the edit; I don't know I was offered the option to submit it for review (though I am in the full-experience website). Anyway, it's not worth worrying about anymore; I think consensus has been reached in the comments. (But of course the question is still open, so others can take the usual actions of editing the question or submitting answers.)

Comment: @DanBron I've struggled with the mobile version of the site also, so I empathize :)